# how to find euclidean distance between pixels within a image in opencv

Tags: c++, image, opencv, matrix

```
int main(){
    Mat cmp, Ref, Diff;
    cmp = imread("image1.tif", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
    Ref = imread("image2.tif", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
    ShiftChk(cmp, Ref);
    absdiff(cmp, Ref, Diff);
    imshow("difference image", Diff);
    waitKey(0);
    double min, max;
    minMaxLoc(Diff, &min, &max);
    Point min_loc, max_loc;
    minMaxLoc(Diff, &min, &max, &min_loc, &max_loc);
    Size sz = Diff.size();
    cout << "max val : " << max << endl;//5
    cout << "max val: " << max_loc << endl; //[26,38]


    vector<vector<double>>test;
    for (int i = 0; i < Diff.cols; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Diff.rows; j++) {

            Point difference = Diff.at<uchar>(26, 38) - Diff.at<uchar>(j, i);
            double dist = sqrt(difference.x*difference.x + difference.y*difference.y);              
            test.push_back(dist);
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to find the Euclidean distance between a single point in an image to all other pixels. The distance values are to be stored in vector test but its showing some error in it. And also I don't know whether the logic I have used is correct to give the right answer(Euclidean distance). Can anyone help me out. Thanks in advance

Error message is:

```
error C2664: 
'void std::vector<std::vector<double,std::allocator<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>>>::push_back(const std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>> &)' : 
cannot convert argument 1 from 'double' to 'std::vector<double,std::allocator<_Ty>> &&'
```

Comment: Error 1 error C2664: 'void std::vector<std::vector<double,std::allocator<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>>>::push_back(const std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>> &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'double' to 'std::vector<double,std::allocator<_Ty>> &&' d\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Source.cpp 39 1

Comment: Did you mean `vector<double> test;` instead of `vector<vector<double>> test;`?

Comment: 2 IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>>, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>>>]" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (double)
            object type is: std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>>, std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>>>> d:\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Source.cpp 39 11

Comment: I am trying to use 2D vector to store answer of dist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two major issues:

1. You're appending the values to the `test` vector wrong. You need either to create an intermediate vector and `push_back` it to `test` (as shown in [@0X0nosugar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40742917/5008845)), or better initialize your vectors with correct dimensions and put the value at the right place.

   ```
   vector<vector<double>> test(Diff.rows, vector<double>(Diff.cols));
   for (int i = 0; i < Diff.rows; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < Diff.cols; j++) {
           test[i][j] = ...       
       }
   }
   ```

   As shown in the snippet above, it's better (and faster) to scan by rows, becuase OpenCV stores images row-wise.
2. You are not computing the distance between two points. You are in fact taking the difference of the values at two given points and creating a `Point` object out of this (which makes no sense). Also you can avoid to compute explicitly the euclidean distance. You can use `cv::norm`:

   ```
    test[i][j] = norm(Point(38, 26) - Point(j, i)); // Pay attention to i,j order!
   ```

Putting all together:

```
Point ref(38, 26);
vector<vector<double>> test(Diff.rows, vector<double>(Diff.cols));
for (int i = 0; i < Diff.rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < Diff.cols; j++) {
        test[i][j] = norm(ref - Point(j,i));      
    }
}
```